# How to make a div dragable and always visible with React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Using React I need to have a div that can be draggable (can be moved around) and always be visible inclusive if the user decides to scroll the respective webpage. For the draggable feature I think I could use:

https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable

but it is not clear for me how to make it always visible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might want a library to determine your user's scroll position.
I find this library to be useful.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-provide-scroll-position

You can then set your Draggable component to a position, the offset to the scroll.